# ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.github.hatamiarash7:RTL-Toast:1.3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library, android-toast

This error only happening in android studio 3.5. I don't know why because I have used this same library in my other projects but after upgrading to the latest android studio which is 3.5, I am having this issue. I have checked and tried some answers but I was unable to solve it.

**The error:**

> ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.github.hatamiarash7:RTL-Toast:1.3
>
> Show in Project Structure dialog
>
> Affected Modules: app

**The library:**

```
implementation 'com.github.hatamiarash7:RTL-Toast:1.3'
```

**My apps dependencies section:**

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.+'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.+'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.+'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.+'
// circle image view
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'

implementation 'com.github.hatamiarash7:RTL-Toast:1.3'

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must define [JitPack](https://jitpack.io/docs/) in your root `build.gradle`:

```
allprojects {
   repositories {
        ...
     maven {
       url 'https://jitpack.io'
     }
   }
}
```

and you will use this dependency:

```
implementation 'com.github.hatamiarash7:RTL-Toast:1.3'
```

Comment: My bad , now i got this.Thanks for your help.